# how to kill spark job of a spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

can we kill one of the jobs(time consuming) of a running spark application and move on to next job  ?

Let us say , there are 50 jobs in a Spark Application and one of them is taking more time (may be it requires more memory than what we have configured) , So can we kill that job and move on to next job ?

and then we can run that job(that action which triggers that job) later with higher memory configuration

If this is not possible then how to handle these conditions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can kill running job by:

- opening Spark application UI.
- going to <kbd>jobs</kbd> tab.
- find job among running jobs.
- click on `kill` link and confirm.